# Input fields of form in bootstrap modal is not reset when modal is closed

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a form in bootstrap modal. For the first time it is empty but when i am opening it for the second time it still contains the field which were filled previously. I tried with

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
        $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    });
});
```

but it is not working

Comment: Try `$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing. When you are closing the modal at that time clear input, textarea fields. So when next time you will open modal all fields will be empty.

```
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $(this)
    .find("input,textarea,select")
       .val('')
       .end()
    .find("input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]")
       .prop("checked", "")
       .end();
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5LCSU/